# How do I put color into a rectangle in a canvas using a dropdown list onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get the rectangle in the canvas to appear and try an fill it with color corresponding to the color on the drop down menu but i just cannot seem to get around it, any suggestions? (coursework)
**strong text**

```js
window.onload = init;
window.onload = myFunction;

function init() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(70, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(120, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(170, 20, 10, 60);
}


function changeColor() {
  var eID = document.getElementById("colors");
  var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value;
  var colortxt = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById('colorDiv').style.background = colortxt;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <div id="content ">
      <center>
         <canvas id="colorDiv " width="300 " height="300 " style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3; ">
         </canvas>
         <select id="colors " onchange="changeColor() ">
            <option value="1 ">Black</option>
            <option value="2 ">Brown</option>
            <option value="3 ">Red</option>
            <option value="4 ">orange</option>
            <option value="5 ">Yellow</option>
            <option value="6 ">Blue</option>
            <option value="7 ">Violet</option>
            <option value="8 " selected="selected ">Grey</option>
         </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: You can find a working code in the answer below. However, I would suggest that you used jquery/angularjs for this functionality instead, to reduce LOC and improve security.

Comment: Thank you! really appreciate it pal!

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple handlers here :

```
window.onload = init;
window.onload = myFunction;
```

your canvas id is  `colorDiv` not `mycanvas` as you are using here :

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

Comment: thankyou, but even after iv made these changes it wont let me link the rectangle inside the canvas to the corresponding color in the drop down menu? any ideas, something i might be missing?

Comment: @javaconfused make sure `changeColor()` is defined before your use it in `onchange`

Answer (score 0):

In all your ids and values you have a space appended.
Use

```
<select id="colors" onchange="changeColor()">
```

instead of

```
<select id="colors " onchange="changeColor() ">
```

And make similar changes elsewhere.

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p1bzeryt/4/

**UPDATE**

Change the selector id "myCanvas" to colorDiv as suggested by @Ramanlfc
and use this function

```
function fillColor(color) {
  var c = document.getElementById("colorDiv");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(70, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(120, 20, 10, 60);
  ctx.fillRect(170, 20, 10, 60);
}
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p1bzeryt/6/

You may call fillColor("white") onload, if you need to.

Comment: i appriciate that! i have got the canvas changing color, but i am trying to get the rectangle in the canvas change color upon selecting from the drop down menu, but the rectangle wont show and i am not sure how to call the function.